# Give user access to specific / followed articles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database

So heres what I have and want to do.. I have a main "users" table. And then a "records" table. So when a user signs in, they see their records, but they only have access to specific records. Does anyone know a good method/technique (or know of a good tutorial) as to how to assign table rows to a user (I its relational database).

A similar concept would be like twitter, how users follow others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.com/). It's an online tutorial that creates a twitter like application for zombies. If I recall correctly it will cover your question and give you a good background on the inter relationships of your models as they pertain to the database.